# How to sink changes taken from mysql to another mysql db using Debezium (cdc)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium

I am able to capture the data events from [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). I had followed all the steps from [debezium](/questions/tagged/debezium) [tutorial](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html), but in the tutorial they haven't specified how to sink those changes to another mysql db.
Please help me I am stuck with it I am unable to find proper tutorial for that.

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name mysql -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium -e MYSQL_USER=mysqluser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw debezium/example-mysql:1.1
```

I am capturing changes from this mysql db which is on port 3307

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name mysqltes -p 3308:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium -e MYSQL_USER=mysqluser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw debezium/example-mysql:1.1
```

Now I want to sink those changes to this mysql db which is on port 3308

*Note*: I am using accesing docker through docker toolbox in my windows 10 home

Answer (score 1):

Debezium is a source, not a sink

You need to use confluent jdbc *sink connector* to send events *to a database*

Comment: Can you please provide json-sink file for mysql

Comment: I trust your ability to search online for one of the many Confluent tutorials using the JDBC Sink

Comment: Actually I searched for it and found one but I am getting invalid URL for jdbc:mysql connection url

Comment: Well, sounds like a good opportunity to post a new question